# Stratified cox reg analysis

Tags: r, regression, stratification

I am trying to make a stratified cox reg analysis in R studio, where I want to see the differences in exposure to MT divided by gender.

I used the following code:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(START_AGE, TIME, STATUS) ~ MT + strata(SEX),
    data = sample1)
```

In the output, I only get HR for MT, but I want to see the effect of MT among males and females. Am I doing the code wrong or is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply stratify by `SEX` as you show, you do not get any information about different possible associations between`MT` and outcome as a function of `SEX`. Modeling the way you wrote assumes that there is a single hazard ratio for `MT`, shared by both strata, with the strata simply providing different baseline hazards around which that hazard ratio works.

If you don't care about the association of `SEX` per se with outcome or otherwise need to stratify, use an *interaction* between `MT` and the strata, for example:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(START_AGE, TIME, STATUS) ~ MT * strata(SEX), 
         data = sample1)
```